# History of function calling convention in C

Tags: c, function-prototypes

As I recall, early C (e.g. K&R) allowed anything to be passed on any function call, so the calling convention had to be that the args are pushed right-to-left and the caller clears the stack after the function returns.

I came across a puzzle in a presentation where the solution involves calling `printf` without using any header files at all.  He asserts that in C if you call a function that has not been declared, then the compiler implicitly takes its parameter list as the promoted arguments that it saw you pass.

But, the new prototype-enabled function calling that was introduced on the ramp-up to ANSI C uses a more efficient calling convention, where the called function clears the stack; it is not repeated by each usage.

In my recollection, the two forms were given different linker-visible names, and were incompatible and this was caught at link time.  His example worked, I maintained, because `printf` purposefully uses the old form, to enable whatever and anything to be passed on a call-by-call basis.

He says that the two uses *must* be compatible, mandated by the standard.  I don’t see how that can work unless the compiler always generates the old-style calls.

What is the real situation according to the standard?  And, what is the *history* of this — has it changed over time?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [retrocomputing.se]  would be a better place to ask trivia questions about programming language history.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking, but I think the simple answer is that variadic functions were treated like functions without prototypes.

Comment: Since C89 was defined, it has not been legitimate to call a variadic function like `printf()` without a prototype in scope. It is legitimate to write the prototype yourself if you really want to, but not usually advisable.

Answer (score 4):

The C standard says nothing about calling conventions.

Starting with the 1989 ANSI C standard (equivalent to the 1990 ISO C standard), calling a variadic function like `printf` without a correct declaration in scope has undefined behavior. That declaration must be a *prototype*, and it must include the `, ...` sequence to indicate that a variable number and type(s) of arguments are accepted.

Starting with the 1999 ISO C standard, calling a function with no visible declaration is a *constraint violation*, requiring a diagnostic. (This is about as close as C gets to saying a construct is illegal.) Prior to C99, a called function would be implicitly declared with a return type of `int` and whatever (promoted) arguments appear in the call.

Many C compilers will accept (perhaps with a warning) a call with no declaration, and many probably use a calling convention that makes a call to `printf` with no visible declaration "work". But the language doesn't define the behavior of such a call, and a conforming compiler is free to reject it or to generate code that misbehaves arbitrarily badly.

If you want to call `printf`, just add `#include <stdio.h>` at the top of your source file. That's a lot easier than thinking about what you might be able to get away with for a given compiler.

Comment: *I* would never call without including, in real code.  This is just language trivia from a puzzle.

Comment: In fact it is possible to call `printf` without `#include <stdio.h>` and without undefined behavior. You just have to declare it yourself -- correctly: `int printf(const char * restrict format, ...);` (And if you get the declaration wrong, the compiler isn't required to complain.)

Comment: Additionally, it bears on the question that the variable arguments to a variadic function are indeed subject to the default argument promotions, just as are the arguments to a function that is declared but has no prototype, and as used to be the case for implicitly-declared functions.

Comment: @JohnBollinger are you saying that "guessing a prototype from the first call" was indeed a thing before some time point?  That is, as opposed to allowing a function to be called with any type/number arguments at each call site like in K&R C.

Comment: Not exactly, @JDługosz.  There is a fine, but important, distinction here: a *declaration* of a function does not necessarily provide a *prototype*.  The latter describes the number of arguments and their types, and was introduced in C90.  There are different rules (continuing into C2011) for calling (declared) functions with prototypes and calling those without.  In C90, it was also allowed to call functions that had no declaration in scope at all, and such calls were interpreted as if the function were declared, without a prototype, as a function returning `int`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger So in C90, if you called a function as if it were declared without a prototype, but in another translation unit it *is* defined with a prototype, was it supposed to work?

Comment: @JDługosz: If the declaration is correct, yes -- and it's the same in C99 and C11. The only thing that changed in C99 is that there must be a declaration; that declaration still doesn't have to be a prototype. (Non-prototype declarations and definitions have been "obsolescent" since 1989, but they still haven't been removed from the language.) If you call a non-variadic function whose visible declaration is not a prototype. the promoted types of the arguments must match the actual types given by the definition.

Comment: @JDługosz, it was supposed and did work when the default argument promotions yielded types compatible with the types specified in the prototype in the function definition.  The behavior was undefined if the function definition provided a prototype with at least one parameter type mismatch.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: A function definition defines its parameter types whether it includes a prototype or not. The requirements for callers are the same either way. For example: `double func(x) double x; { /* ... */ }`

Comment: Acknowledged, @KeithThompson.  Apologies for my clumsy wording.